# APCu and APC setting unclear

Tags: php.ini, alternative-php-cache

Please help me to understand where is difference between `APC` and `APCu` lies. While inspecting CentOS web-server (set up not by me) found that it has `APCu` 4.0.2 installed and `phpinfo();` reports that `APC` Emulated.
It was bit confusing, anyway tried to use settings for normal `APC` in `php.ini`

```
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size = 768M                       
apc.cache_by_default = 0                  
apc.filters="+domain.com,+anotherdomain.com"
apc.stat = 0 
apc.max_file_size=2M
```

Then checked `apc.php` status page and it revealed that only `apc.shm_size` changed, but no cache entries for selected domains.  So how can i adapt `APCu` to cache selected domains as `APC` did ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 5.5, PHP comes with the Zend OpCache engine that substitutes APC. APC had two parts. The APC opcache that is no longer used and is instead emulated in php 5.5, and the APC cache that you can use to store data. That part is now used through the APCu extension.